# getting an error moment.moment is not a function, using Jasmine and Moment.js

Tags: unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jasmine, momentjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying out Jasmine in conjuction with moment.js, but I am getting this error...

```
 debug.js:21 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _moment.moment) is not a function
```

not sure if it's related to moment.js or if I am setting up this incorrectly. Appreciate any help.

```js
//script.js

import { moment } from 'moment';

export class Age {
  
  constructor(age, secondDate) {
    this.age = age;
    this.secondDate = secondDate;
  }

  getSecondsBetweenTwoDates(age, secondDate){
    age = moment(this.age).format('l');
    secondDate = moment(this.secondDate).format('l');
    //differenceInSeconds = moment((this.secondDate).diff(this.age, 'days'));
    differenceInDays = age.diff(secondDate, 'days');
    //let differenceInDays = this.age - this.secondDate
    return differenceInDays;

  }
}


//age-spec.js

import { Age } from './../js/age.js';

describe('Age', function() {
  
  let reusableDate,
      today,
      testDate = '2016-10-05',
      date = '2016-10-10';

  beforeEach(() => {
    reusableDate = new Age(date, testDate);
    console.log(reusableDate);
    const mockedDateAndTime  = '2017-03-02 00:00:00';
    today = moment(mockedDateAndTime).toDate();
    console.log('this is today', today);
    jasmine.clock().mockDate(today);
  });

  it('should return the difference between today', () => {
    console.log(date);
    console.log(testDate);
    console.log(reusableDate.getSecondsBetweenTwoDates(date, testDate));
    console.log(typeof(reusableDate.getSecondsBetweenTwoDates));
    //expect(5).toEqual(reusableDate.getSecondsBetweenTwoDates());
  });


});
```

I am not using the beforeEach block at all, that was just something that I found on Google, and was trying ... I also installed a karma-moment plugin like so:

frameworks: ['jquery-3.2.1', 'jasmine', 'browserify', 'moment-2.9.0'],

plugins: [
      'karma-jquery',
      'karma-browserify',
      'karma-moment',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine-html-reporter'
    ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `moment` named export in `moment` package. Most NPM packages are CommonJS/UMD and have their main export as `module.exports`. Even though `moment` was written [as ES module with `default` export](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/40564b1696e9323d6d40abca2fcf3bb8bc658d9e/src/moment.js#L82), it can be imported as UMD module too, because it has [different entry points for different environments](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/40564b1696e9323d6d40abca2fcf3bb8bc658d9e/package.json#L25-L26).

It should be

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

or

```
import moment from 'moment';
```

The choice may depend on project configuration. Generally `* as` reflects real CommonJS export better and is less prone to cause problems if the project was configured to fall back to CJS modules during bundling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

I made a dumb mistake, for some reason my ES6 import syntax at the top of the file was not working.

I changed this on my script.js file:
import { moment } from 'moment';

to this:
var moment = require('moment');

Comment: It doesn't work for very specific reason. Because there's no `moment` named export.